# Pandas New Dataframe Displaying Top and Bottom N Values Per Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with three columns: unit, influencer, and value. There are a few different types of influencers and the values represent the count of the unit. **I want to create a new table displaying the most and least frequent n units for each influencer and their respective values.**

My df looks like this:

```
Unit    Influencer    Value
A       foo           321
B       foo           200
C       foo           20
D       foo           12
E       foo           3
A       bar           999
B       bar           209
C       bar           89
D       bar           34
E       bar           15
F       bar           2
```

My output should look like (lets say we want top and bottom 2 units):

```
Unit    Influencer    Value
    A       foo           321
    B       foo           200
    D       foo           12
    E       foo           3
    A       bar           999
    B       bar           209
    E       bar           15
    F       bar           2
```

I have tried something similar to the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703606/pandas-groupby-top-3-values-for-each-group), but I am getting the error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape," which I assume is because "Influencer" is the index of my df. If my df is multiindex, the new df is created, but it is incorrect.

```
def get_top3(counts, col1, col2):

    top3 = (counts.groupby(col1))[col2].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3)).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('VAL')

    top3 = counts.set_index(np.arange(len(counts)) % 3, append=True)['value'].unstack().add_prefix('VAL')

    return top3
```

However, this creates a Dataframe that looks like:

```
VAL1  VAL2  VAL3
321   NaN   NaN
NaN   200   NaN
NaN   NaN   20
12    NaN   NaN
NaN   3     NaN
...
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I am also open to feedback on how my output df could be formatted. Thanks!

Comment: The 'A' are missing in the output, any specific reason?

Comment: Sorry, I had to move some of my values around and forgot to change the output to reflect that. I have edited the question to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
nlargest = df.groupby('Influencer')['Value'].nlargest(2).reset_index()['level_1'].values
nsmallest = df.groupby('Influencer')['Value'].nsmallest(2).reset_index()['level_1'].values

result = pd.concat([df.iloc[nlargest], df.iloc[nsmallest]]).sort_index()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   Unit Influencer  Value
0     A        foo    321
1     B        foo    200
3     D        foo     12
4     E        foo      3
5     A        bar    999
6     B        bar    209
9     E        bar     15
10    F        bar      2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. I am curious though, why do we need .reset_index() in this case?

Comment: I did that to access the indices in level 1

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
#df=df.sort_values('Value')
g=df.groupby('Influencer')
pd.concat([g.head(2),g.tail(2)]).sort_index()
Out[693]: 
   Unit Influencer  Value
0     A        foo    321
1     B        foo    200
3     D        foo     12
4     E        foo      3
5     A        bar    999
6     B        bar    209
9     E        bar     15
10    F        bar      2
```

Comment: `Hail-Tead` is the appropriate solution and it's performance is better.

Answer (score 1):

try creating a function like:

```
def selc_df(df, x=2):
    return df.head(x).append(df.tail(x))

selc_df(df,2)
```

**Example :**

```
>>> df
   A    B
0  1  345
1  2  366
2  3  299
3  3  455
4  4  879
5  5  321
6  5  957
7  6  543
```

**Result:**

```
>>> def selc_df(df, x=2):
...     return df.head(x).append(df.tail(x))
...

>>> selc_df(df,2)
   A    B
0  1  345
1  2  366
6  5  957
7  6  543
```

Comment: The main issue with this is that I need the head and tail of each influencer, rather than the head and tail of the entire dataframe.